# Is there a good way to override a DNS in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, dns, ip

Basically, I want to make a fake DNS entry for a URL, and force that URL to resolve to a specific IP. Is there a way to do this in iOS that wouldn't get an app rejected? I can't seem to find a way to do this (still at square one). Can anyone point me in the right direction (class reference, third party framework, etc)? If not, is there a rule/policy/something else that I've overlooked which makes it impossible?

Comment: Jailbroken? Will need that probably.

Comment: Depending on your specific situation, this ranges from trivial to impossible. Are you trying to do this within a UIWebView that you control, or are you trying to do this for something other than a web view, but in your app (say for NSURLConnection?), or are you trying to impact applications other than your own (such as MobileSafari)? Do you actually need to modify DNS responses, or do you just want to redirect certain web requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this officially at the iOS app level because the DNS is set by the OS and you can not modify the entries due to the iOS Sandbox. This means it is not possible if you are creating an app which you'll submit to the Apple App Store. You could build something within your own app where if you have some browser, you intercept the URL and redirect it but of course this will be local within your app and not when the user uses Mobile Safari or Chrome etc.

If you are creating an app for Jailbroken devices, you could modify the `/etc/hosts` file and add your entry there

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I expected that might have been the case, but I thought I'd check. I guess we'll have to find a way around it since Apple says "nuh-uh"

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:
Let's say, you want to GET `http://httpbin.org/get`,
and you don't want to use domian, but use ip address `54.175.219.8`,
you can just make a request, set `http://54.175.219.8/get` as `path`, and add a new http header: {"host": "httpbin.org"}.

General solution:
Implement your own NSURLProtocol like https://github.com/mattt/NSEtcHosts